# como redirigir desde ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Muy buenas tengo un problema para redirigir desde usa solicitud post de ajax

el problemas es el siguiente:

tengo un div el cual recibe solo todos los textos de validación que podrían ocurrir en la solicitud

```html
  <div id="resultado">

  </div>
```

y tengo mi solicitud de ajax

```html
$(function(){
          $("#btn_entrar").click(function(){
                var url = "clases/loginclass.php";
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: $("#frm_login").serialize(),
                    success: function(data){

                        if(data.redirect){
                           window.location.href = data.redirect;

                        }else {
                            $("#resultado").html(data);
                        }

                    }
                });

                return false;
          });
        });
```

al momento de querer redirigir desde el documento loginclass.php  con el codigo

```html
  header('Location: ../reporte.php');
```

no ocurre nada  que estoy haciendo mal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizalo con `window.location` o `locación.href`, asumo que en `data.redirect` tienes una `URL`:

```
  $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: $("#frm_login").serialize(),
                        success: function(data){

                            if(data.redirect){
                               location.href = "http://www.miweb/destino";

                            }else {
                                $("#resultado").html(data);
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

El return false no es necesario.